# How to fix Gutenberg's Convert to Blocks?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When I update something in my Gutenberg's JS code and save it, that block is broken in all of my posts wherever it is used and following error is being displayed:

[image]

Can you please let me know how to fix this error (without removing and re-adding block as a fix because I might have 100+ posts!)

Comment: can you show the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Actually the code is not required, because this is a common problem and someone should have answer!

Comment: This is because, Either you changed the block HTML structure after use or your edit function HTML nodes don't match with save function HTML nodes.